# display ngFor with json object return from service

Tags: angular

This is my service:
https://api.myjson.com/bins/quv59

Im trying to display it in my html

```
*ngFor="let item of booksList; let i = index"
```

my ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.booksDataService.getBooks().subscribe(
  function(response) { 
    this.booksList = response.books;
  },
);}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer for the help of other people...
call to the service:

```
this.booksDataService.getBooks()
    .subscribe(
        allBooks => this.booksList = allBooks);}
```

html:

```
*ngFor="let item of booksList.books; let i = index"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <li *ngFor="let item of booksList; let i = index">
    {{ item.author }} 
  </li>
```

Comment: I even didnt try to print the value - i have some hard coded just cant see anything...
This is my service but when i print booklist to the log i can see array of 7 objects so i beleive it's ok

Comment: @eladr item of bookList.Books

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using async pipe:

```
*ngFor="let item of booksDataService.getBooks() | async; let i = index"
```

Comment: I wouldn't services in templates.  AoT will fail.

Comment: @wesside Can you please share a link with more information about that?

Comment: The linked issue discusses private members only unless I am missing something. I don't see a mention of services per se.

Comment: Expose your service, be my guest